# "Show X items per page" tooltips are in English for all international sites

Tags: bug, localization, tooltips, transifex

At the bottom right of the Active Questions page, the "Show X items per page" tooltip for all the international sites is in English.  Take [SO in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=active&pagesize=50), for example.  Hover over this, and the tooltip is in English:

[image]

Hover over a number on this, and the tooltips are in Russian:

[image]

This also extends to the tooltips for the votes cast/flags/reputation buttons on the profile page:

[image]

If these strings aren't translated yet, can we add them to Transifex?  If they are, can we fix the tooltips?

Comment: They are in https://traducir.win